# Form will not submit after jquery validate remote method

Tags: jquery, validation

This is my code which does the remote validation perfectly as it is intended. However The form will not submit. When I check chrome debugger no call is made to submit the form. When I remove the remote validation rule the form is submitted. When i remove the remote rule and replace with other basic required rules the form does submit. With no error message its hard to see what I am doing wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
$("#register_student_2").validate({
 rules: {

          relationship: {
             required:true,
               remote: {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "includes/check-relationship.php",
                    data: {
                          fieldData : function() {
                            return $("#relationship").val();
                          }                           
                     },
                    dataType:"json",
                    dataFilter: function(data) {
                        var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        if(json.error == "true") {
                            return "\"" + json.errorMessage + "\"";
                        } else {
                            return success;

                        }

                    }
                }
             },           
           },




submitHandler: function (form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
         beforeSubmit: function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 'slow');
            $("#reg-output1").html('output some html');
        },
        clearForm: true,
  success: function (data) {
            var msg_parts = data.split("|");
            if (msg_parts[0] == "success") {
                $("#reg-output1").html('output some more html');
                $('#li_complete_registration').removeClass('disabled');
                $("#complete_registration").attr('href','#href_complete_registration');

            } else {
                $("#reg-output1").html('output even more html')
            }
        },
    });




}
});
```

Comment: can u share the fiddle

Comment: If your problem in the validation process, you should debug that file... (if a complex one don't work, and the simple one does, for sure there's a problem in the first)  **I will suggest to simplify at maximun your file, and then, uncomment line by line, to see where is the problem**. Share if you want that file too.. to have more info.